# Changing the time of Date() object jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I need to set a cookie to expire at midnight of the day that it is set, but I'm struggling to get my head about jQuery `Date();`.

I'm using the [jQuery Cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) to control the cookies. By default it just accepts an `int` as the expiry time, but you can pass it a date object according to the docs. So I'm trying to use jQuery `Date();` and edit just the `hrs` `mins` `secs` to set it to `23:59:59`.

When I use Date it outputs something like this: `Mon Oct 28 2013 10:59:30 GMT+0000 (GMT)`

Does anyone know how to hook into just the hours, mins and seconds part of this?

Thanks!

Comment: Tip: `Date()` has nothing to do with jQuery. It's purely Javascript.

Answer (score 3):

Fix:

```
var date = new Date();

date.setHours(23,59,59,0);                  

// set the new item as a cookie
$.cookie(count, newItem, { expires: date });
```

Changes `Mon Oct 28 2013 11:17:55 GMT+0000 (GMT)`

to `Mon Oct 28 2013 23:59:59 GMT+0000 (GMT)`